Derivation of Darcy's law for linear flow from differential form
In H. Dale Beggs' Production Optimization using Nodal Analysis, the following is presented as the differential form of Darcy's law:
$$q = vA = -\frac{kA}{\mu}\frac{dp}{dx}$$
The author then goes on to state the following:

For linear flow, that is for constant area flow, the equation may be integrated to give
pressure drop occuring over some length  L
$$\int^{p_2}_{p_1}\frac{kdp}{\mu} = -\frac{q\mu}{kA}\int^L_0dx$$

I'm trying to figure out the intermediate steps between the differential form and the form for linear flow. I suppose one could start by multiplying both sides by $-\frac{\mu}{kA}$ and obtain the following:
$$-\frac{q\mu}{kA} = \frac{dp}{dx}$$
But then I'm not sure how you can separate the $dp$ and the $dx$ portions of the differential as the author has done. What mathematical laws allow for this?
